# Is it possible to give callback for threads created using Thread class

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to give callback(announcing completion of activity) for threads created using Thread class. I have created the thread the following way but could not find a way to give the callback.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(StartPoll);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Not directly. But you can always do something like:

```
new Thread(() => { StartPoll(); Callback(); })
```

Comment: Very clever. Beats creating another class and assigning a delegate and so forth when all you want to do is just call a simple method when it's done.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the apartment state to STA is not enough, the second requirement is that you must pump a message loop.  Application.Run() in either Winforms or WPF.  It is actually the message loop that permits marshaling a call to a specific thread.  Implemented by respectively Control.Begin/Invoke and Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke().

That's however more of a UI implementation detail.  The generic solution is very similar to what the UI thread does, you use a thread-safe queue and a loop in the "main" thread to read objects from the queue.  Like a delegate you can invoke.  A standard solution to the [producer/consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  The .NET 4 BlockingCollection class makes it easy.  Rewriting the thread code so it loops and stays responsive to worker requests is not always so easy.